# Citation produces question mark?

Tags: citing

I am struggling to show the citation properly but nothing worked so far. The output is `?` . below is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Thesis}
\author{Author Name}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

This document refer to \cite{einstein} 

\bibliography{TEST}

\end{document}
```

out:
[image]

Here is my `.bib`

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try adding 
`\bibliographystyle{plain}` (or the style you like) before `\bibliography{TEST}`.

Comment: Thank you. But I tried already and did not work. something like: `\bibliographystyle{apa-6th-edition}`

Comment: @Sam_9090 - Without a valid `\bibliographystyle` instruction, BibTeX literally doesn't know which style to apply -- and hence produces nothing at all; actually, it'll produce qyuestio marks. May I suggest you start slowly and use (say) the `plain` bibliography style. Once you get the hang of things, then start looking around for what other bibliogarphy styles.

Comment: I downloaded the `apa-6th-edition.csl` file and used in `\bibliographystyle{..}`. is that wrong?

Comment: csl files are *not* for use with BibTeX. No exceptions.